# MySQL query for cloning yesterday values to new ones with current date

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following MySQL data which I enter daily (currency exchange rates).

Some days I need to copy yesterday's rates for today and in that case I manually create by hand new records in my application with same values and today's date.

Is there a way on MySQL level to run a query for this daily "cloning" process when all today values remain the same as yesterday, except of course the date?

### For example

#### Yesterday rates

SUBDATE(NOW(),1)

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ date       ║ net_price ║ sell_rate ║ currency ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1  ║ 2017-08-10 ║ 0.9088    ║ 1.0401    ║ GBP      ║
║ 2  ║ 2017-08-10 ║ 1.1801    ║ 0.8010    ║ USD      ║
║ 3  ║ 2017-08-10 ║ 1.1361    ║ 0.8494    ║ CHF      ║
║ 4  ║ 2017-08-10 ║ 1.4964    ║ 0.6282    ║ CAD      ║
║ 5  ║ 2017-08-10 ║ 1.4968    ║ 0.6280    ║ AUD      ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

#### Today rates

[net_price, sell_rate, currency] will be copied to new records for CURDATE()

*date is not getting its value automatically by MySQL, application enters its value on new records*

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ date       ║ net_price ║ sell_rate ║ currency ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 6  ║ 2017-08-11 ║ 0.9088    ║ 1.0401    ║ GBP      ║
║ 7  ║ 2017-08-11 ║ 1.1801    ║ 0.8010    ║ USD      ║
║ 8  ║ 2017-08-11 ║ 1.1361    ║ 0.8494    ║ CHF      ║
║ 9  ║ 2017-08-11 ║ 1.4964    ║ 0.6282    ║ CAD      ║
║ 10 ║ 2017-08-11 ║ 1.4968    ║ 0.6280    ║ AUD      ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

*(For example's sake we do not care about the official daily change of forex rates)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert from and to the same table yesterday's records:

```
INSERT INTO rates (date, net_price, sell_rate, currency)
SELECT CURDATE(), net_price, sell_rate, currency
FROM rates
WHERE date = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
```

This answer is somewhat contrived, because it assumes that you somehow already know that the forex data has not changed day-over-day, or has changed so little, that just cloning yesterday's data is satisfactory.

Comment: After your correction edit on your answer to `SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)` it works like a charm !

Comment: Your date column is in mysql date type, not datetime type, it's for that :)

Comment: @Mcsky you've right, I corrected it on my question :)